# Python file path failing in pycharm regex confusion

Tags: python, regex

I am a relatively new python user and am getting a funky error using my IDE (pycharm), but not when using the cmd line.

Simply I:

```
path ='C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\users.dat'

import pandas as pd
unames = ['user_id', 'gender', 'age', 'occupation', 'zip']
users = pd.read_table(path, sep='::', header=None, names=unames)
```

After which I receive an error that indicates:

```
ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not 
support regex separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
ParserWarning)
```

When i input the identical commands into the cmd line and print `users` the data prints as expected (i.e., no errors or anything funky).

EDIT: similarly when I input

```
ratingsdata ='C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\ratings.dat'
```

I get a funky `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:` Not sure as to why the `/r` is not ok in a file path... I understand it's regex, but within the quoted lines??

Help!

Comment: What version of Python and Pandas are you using?

Comment: @NathanTuggy That would help - Python 2.7 and pandas installed for 2.7... does that help? Also, I found the error is more like a warning rather than a failed attempt... However, I don't get the warning in the cmd line...

Comment: To avoid the warning you can specify the engine,read_table(engine = "python")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Looks like](//stackoverflow.com/questions/25204642/read-csv-with-character-delimiter-with-the-c-engine) on Python 2.7 Pandas just doesn't handle separators that look regexish. The initial "error" can be worked around by adding `engine='python'` as a named parameter in the call, as suggested in the warning.

Comment: @gh0strider18, add it as a named parameter within the parentheses of the read_table call.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are attempting to do an exercise from the "Python For Data Analysis" book, I ran into this same issue.  All you have to do is use double slashes instead of single slashes like so:

`path ='C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\ratings.dat'`

Answer (score 5):

If you are working through "Python for Data Analysis" and using PyCharm with Python 3.x, here is where to specify the engine:

```
ratings = pd.read_table(path + '/ratings.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=rnames, engine='python')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `engine = 'python'` as a parameter just before the end bracket.

**For Example:**

```
ratings = pd.read_table('.../iPythonNotebooks/1mil_movie_reco/ml-1m/ratings.dat',
                        sep='::', header=None, names=rnames, engine = 'python')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in El Capitan using Python 3. My csv file had a space after all the separators (;) so I used the delimiter '; ' (with a space) in the read_csv call, thus I received the warning.

So I deleted all spaces from the csv file (which was comprised exclusively of integers) and the warning disappeared. Then I added a third column with a header named "some text" without the quotes and data also with spaces. I had to call the column using ['col_name'] so the print function could do its job

```
dataFile = pd.read_csv("dude.csv", sep = ';')
col2 = dataFile.col2
col3 = dataFile['some text']
print(col2)
print(col3)
```